# Real v.s. in reality

Tags: differences

Yesterday, I talked with Emma. I said:

> ‘‘Those indulging in the social media often live up to the needs of their followers on the social media but neglect their real families.’’

However, Emma thought "their real families" should be changed into "their families in reality" because she believed if "a real family" is acceptable,"a fake family" will be too.
But,"a fake family"sounded weird to her,so she didn't think "a real family" was correct.
What do you think? 
Are they different in this sentence?

Comment: Both mean essentially the same thing, but *real family* is more natural and idiomatic. An alternative to both would be *their real-life families*, or even *their actual families*.

Comment: @JasonBassford thanks for help.：) Oh…I found I had forgot to tape her reason for "family in reality"… sorry,but would you know whether the process of her reasoning is right?  If you know,tell me, please.

Comment: In this example, I would say that the opposite of *real* family would be *virtual* family, and there's nothing wrong with that phrase. In fact, it doesn't sound strange.

Comment: @JasonBassford I can't agree with you more. Tankhs for your help.^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **real families** and **families in real life** mean essentially the same thing.

In general, **real families** is more natural and idiomatic.

However, if having a discussion with people in the specific context of social media, then **in real life** could be more appropriate. (Online communities such as those in [Second Life](https://secondlife.com/) will often use the acronym *IRL* to talk about the world outside the game.)

Two alternatives to both phrases are *real-life families* and *actual families*.

---

In response to an update to your question, I would not say that **fake families** would be the opposite of **real families** in this context.

Instead, the opposite of **real families** would actually be something like **virtual families**, and that's something that doesn't sound strange.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my opinion,what you said is what I thought ：)ha